# How does this python code work?

Tags: python

I have just started writing some simple scripts in python as I've started using ubuntu as my default operating system.

So I came across the code for mpsyt (terminal youtube player). I was surprised how simple the coding was. Could anybody explain what is going on here? I don't undestand how a seemingly complex program could have such a small amount of code....

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'mps-youtube==0.2.5','console_scripts','mpsyt'
 __requires__ = 'mps-youtube==0.2.5'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
sys.exit(
    load_entry_point('mps-youtube==0.2.5', 'console_scripts', 'mpsyt')()
)
```

Comment: This is an autogenerated stub; it executes an entry point in the `mps-youtube` package installed in your `site-packages`. It is *not* the actual script.

Answer (score 4):

This is an autogenerated stub; it executes an entry point in the `mps-youtube` package installed in your `site-packages`. It is *not* the actual script.

The `setuptools` project installs such stubs in the `bin` directory; it's task is to find the right version of the project and load the *real* script.

There will be a matching `lib/python[version]/mps-youtube-0.2.5-py[version].egg-info` directory holding metadata, including an `entry_points.txt` file that contains INI-file-format style information on the package. The `load_entry_point('mps-youtube==0.2.5', 'console_scripts', 'mpsyt')` line will look for that exact file to load the `mpsyt` definition from the `console_scripts` section.

In the `[console_scripts]` section there will be a `mpsyt` entry that names the actual module used to run the script. Judging by the [project `setup.py` file](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube/blob/develop/setup.py#L28) that'll look like this:

```
[console_scripts]
mpsyt = mps_youtube:main.main
```

pointing to the `mps_youtube.main` module, where the `main()` function will be called to do the actual work; look for a `lib/python[version]/mps_youtube/main.py` file, then search for a `def main():` function definition. From Github you can see the [actual script is a little longer](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube/blob/develop/mps_youtube/main.py#L3887-L3987).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the entire program. This just runs the rest of the program.